# Does Junit shut down all the threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I have a Junit class with 6 tests in them. When the first test runs, it calls one of the methods in my other class which starts a new Thread(). Let's call it `MyThread`.

The idea is for `MyThread` to keep running for a bit longer after the JUnit tests are done.

For example, for all the JUnit tests to be done, it would take 1 secs, and so I would set `MyThread` to run for 3 secs:

```
new Thread(new Runable(){
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("start");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}).start();
```

The `start` would be shown on the standard output, but the `end` is never shown.

It seems to me that whenever the JUnit tests are done, `MyThread` is shut down as well.

So I am wondering, does JUnit shut down all the threads it initiates? Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, Context: All my 6 tests connects to a HSQLDB in-process DB to do some job. Since I don't want to close the connection each time a test runs, I have them share one connection. I started a Thread to monitor the tests, when all finishes, it would then close the connection and all. But that thread is terminated every time when my JUnit tests ends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not JUnit but the external systems which run JUnit test (like Eclipse or Maven) who are responsible for terminating JVM. Those call System.exit which stops all the threads. If JUnit did it then the external system would have no chance to process the results.

Answer (score 1):

To address the additional context given in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147708/does-junit-shut-down-all-the-threads?noredirect=1#comment26580466_18147708), I would suggest this is exactly what `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods are for.

Create the (static) DB connection in your `@BeforeClass` and close it in the `@AfterClass` method. No need to have a background method waiting around for other tests to finish.